# Why JQuery 2.x was removed since jquery_update-7.x-3.0-alpha2?

Tags: 7, javascript

I noticed Version 2.1 of JQuery was removed from [JQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/node/2497333) module since 7.x-3.0-alpha2.
Is there any particular reason for that I should be aware of?

Comment: As far as I can see, on 7.x-3-alpha3 was removed jQuery 1.9. 7.x-3.0-alpha2 didn't remove any jQuery version.

Comment: Are you sure? I can't find any commit in its git repo which removed the jQuery 2.1

Comment: I will check, although I can't use version 2.1 with latest dev/stable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 2.1 has not been removed; [its files are still present in the 7.x-3.x-dev](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/jquery_update/tree/replace/jquery?h=7.x-3.x) development snapshot.
What eventually was done is updating the version 2.1 files to version 2.1.4, since they don't keep multiple 2.1.x versions (e.g. 2.1.0, 2.1.1., 2.1.3).